# How to judge the convergence of this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\nu _{n}^{s}=\nu _{1}^{s}+\nu _{2}^{s}+\cdots +\nu _{n}^{s}+\cdots$$
where $\nu _{1}=\sin x>0~,~\nu _{n+1}=\sin \nu _{n}~,~n=1,2,\cdots$

I don't know how to do it.What 's' will make the series divergent or convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for
"iterated sine",
you will find that
$v_n
\approx \sqrt{3/n}
$.

Therefore,
$v_n^s
\approx (3/n)^{s/2}
=3^{s/2}n^{-s/2}
$.

Since
$\sum \frac1{n^x}
$
converges for
$x > 1$
and diverges for
$x \le 1$,
$\sum v^s_n$
converges for
$s > 2$
and diverges for
$s \le 2$.

Comment: For divergence, one has to contend with $\nu_1\neq 1$ (perhaps by travelling far enough in the sequence $\sin^n 1$ such that we arrive at an element $<\nu_1$).